# Show multiple divs base on input

Tags: javascript

i hava an input type number

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id ="nbchambre" name="nbchambre" onchange="myFunction()">
```

I have another input that i want to show multiple times based on the number that the user enter, now i wrote this javascript code:

```
function myFunction(){
            var n = document.getElementById("nbchambre").value;
            for(count = 1; count < n+1; count++){
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'test';
                document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
            }
        }
```

but this code doesn't work, when ever i write a number the div will show the word 'test' 10 times the number (for example when i write 3 it will show the word test 30 times), also when i write 5 after i wrote 3 it will add 50 'test' to the first 30 'test'.  I am not good at javascript so please help me fix this code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you are converting your input value to a number. Otherwise it will be treated as a string.

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id ="nbchambre" name="nbchambre" onchange="myFunction()">

<div id="content"></div>
<script>
function myFunction(){
            var n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
            var content = document.getElementById('content');
            content.innerHTML="";
            for(var count = 1; count < n+1; count++){
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'test';
                content.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: Wow it work!! thanks a lot!! just one other question!! write now the user need to write a number then press 'enter'.. is it possible to make the script work instantly after he write the number?

Comment: They don't have to press enter. As soon as it loses focus it fire. But you can add an "onkeydown" event if you want to fire it as soon as they press a key

Comment: Yes, you can make your function run instantly in response to the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) with [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). So the function would run whenever the user types anything.